# Spring Boot, SQLFeatureNotSupportedException при старте приложения

Tags: postgresql, исключения, spring-boot, spring-data

создаю новый Spring Boot проект, при старте выкидывает **exception:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.a2lpo.taskblock.taskblock.TaskblockApplication.main(TaskblockApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Метод org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() ещё не реализован
at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:688) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1269) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
... 49 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

В базе, при этом, таблица создается. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Добавьте в app.properties: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.